# How to use Android L Serif Font in TextView

Tags: android, fonts

I have seen many apps implement the Material design serif font (Noto), but can't figure out how to do this in a TextView. I have already tried adding the attribute             android:typeface="serif", but it looks like the default Roboto font. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not aware that Noto is baked into Android 5.x. My guess is that you have to bundle it with your app and use it like any other external font.

Comment: Ah, ok. Will try that. Weird that the typeface="" doesn't do anything, though. Still sans-serif.